# How to use if nested in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, nested

i have a problem regarding using if else nested in php, the `$hasilkonsentrasi` is unreadable, Thankyou

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <?php  
   if ($hasil[0] > $hasil[1]) {
    if ($hasil[0] > $hasil[2]) {
     if ($hasil[0] > $hasil[3]) {
     $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Keamanan Jaringan";
     }     
    }
   }
   elseif ($hasil[1] > $hasil[0]) {
    if ($hasil[1] > $hasil[2]) {
     if ($hasil[1] > $hasil[3]) {
      $hasilkonsentrasi = "Teknologi Cerdas";
     }
    }
   }
   elseif ($hasil[2] > $hasil[0]) {
    if ($hasil[2] > $hasil[1]) {
     if ($hasil[2] > $hasil [3]) {
      $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Bisnis";
     }

    }
   }
   elseif ($hasil[3] > $hasil[0]) {
    if ($hasil[3] > $hasil[1]) {
     if ($hasil[3] > $hasil[2]) {
      $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Data dan Informasi";
     }

    }
   }
   echo "Anda cocok mengambil konsentrasi <strong>$hasilkonsentrasi</strong>";


  $mkj= number_format($hasil[0], 2, '.', '');
  $tc=$hasil[1];
  $mb=$hasil[2];
  $mdi=$hasil[3];
  $jurusan=$hasilkonsentrasi;
  $user->SimpanHasilJurusan($mkj,$tc,$mb,$mdi,$jurusan);
  ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean `$hasilkonsentrasi` is unreadable? And you can probably clean those if-blocks up to make them more readable.

Comment: Please, use English words in your variables and strings, so everybody can understand the context and the problem in order to help you

Comment: i give some logic instrument, sorry if i cant open that code clearly. this is the logic:
a is  1.75
b is 1.67
c is  1.82
d is  1.87
and `$hasilkonsentrasi` will be "d", where the value of "d" is greater than all
thank you for ur respond

Answer (score 1):

syntax

```html
if (condition) {
    code to be executed if this condition is true;
} elseif (condition) {
    code to be executed if first condition is false and this condition is true;
} else {
    code to be executed if all conditions are false;
}
```

try this one in last else there is no need to add condition

```html
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <?php  
   if ($hasil[0] > $hasil[1]) {
    if ($hasil[0] > $hasil[2]) {
     if ($hasil[0] > $hasil[3]) {
     $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Keamanan Jaringan";
     }     
    }
   }
   elseif ($hasil[1] > $hasil[0]) {
    if ($hasil[1] > $hasil[2]) {
     if ($hasil[1] > $hasil[3]) {
      $hasilkonsentrasi = "Teknologi Cerdas";
     }
    }
   }
   elseif ($hasil[2] > $hasil[0]) {
    if ($hasil[2] > $hasil[1]) {
     if ($hasil[2] > $hasil [3]) {
      $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Bisnis";
     }

    }
   }
   else {
    if ($hasil[3] > $hasil[1]) {
     if ($hasil[3] > $hasil[2]) {
      $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Data dan Informasi";
     }

    }
   }
   echo "Anda cocok mengambil konsentrasi <strong>$hasilkonsentrasi</strong>";


  $mkj= number_format($hasil[0], 2, '.', '');
  $tc=$hasil[1];
  $mb=$hasil[2];
  $mdi=$hasil[3];
  $jurusan=$hasilkonsentrasi;
  $user->SimpanHasilJurusan($mkj,$tc,$mb,$mdi,$jurusan);
  ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, but theres still error where `$hasilkonsetrasi` still unreadable. Sory for bad english , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for is the key of the `$hasil` entry with the largest value. There are many ways to do this, but I would suggest [sorting the array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), while preserving keys, and then use a switch on the key value. like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <?php  
   arsort($hasil);
   switch(array_key_first($hasil)) {
     case 0  : $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Keamanan Jaringan";
               break;   
     case 1  : $hasilkonsentrasi = "Teknologi Cerdas";
               break;   
     case 2  : $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Bisnis";
               break;   
     case 3  : $hasilkonsentrasi = "Manajemen Data dan Informasi";
               break;   
     default : $hasilkonsentrasi = "Not found";
               break;   
   }
   echo "Anda cocok mengambil konsentrasi <strong>$hasilkonsentrasi</strong>";
  ?>
</div>
```

This is also still doable when there are 6 entries in the array, whereas if you wanted to do that with `if () else` the code would really become unreadable.

Comment: Very nice answer! :-)

Comment: that's what exactly i'm searching for, but unfortunately there some problem :
1. i'm using old php
2. i'm using what [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) tell, but there was error like `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to array_key_first() must be of the type array, boolean given`
Thank you for ur reply, sory for bad english

Comment: @MadeSuralaga Sorry, that was my mistake, I have corrected the code. Please note that `arsort($hasil);` actually changes (sorts) `$hasil`. If you don't want that you have to use a copy of the array.